# cannot find module "angular2/angular"

Tags: angular, typescript

I am following Angular js tutorial from https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

and I am trying to use this code:

```
import {bootstrap, Component} from 'angular2/angular2';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
class AppComponent { }
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

but I get this error:

> cannot find module "angular2/angular"

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

Comment: have you check this part https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#add-index-html- ?

Comment: @PankajParkar is it related to this error ?

Comment: as a workaround, you can put a path in front thus `../typings/angular2/angular2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tsd for angular2 does not actually create the typings file in your typings directory instead it needs to be installed using node:

```
npm install -save angular2
```

Then in your tsdconfig.json, you need to enable node module resolution under compilerOptions:

```
"moduleResolution": "node"
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I placed tsconfig.json to root but getting different error http://prntscr.com/9anlzk.  my tsconfig file look like this: http://prntscr.com/9anmn1

Comment: I think it shouldn't be under wwwroot either, just under the project root at the same level as project.json. This is my project structure http://imgur.com/gV1QLLv

Comment: that didnt work either. I started getting cannot find module "angular2/angular" Please check this http://prntscr.com/9anwyq. by the way I am not using gulpfile.

Comment: Can you move the typings folder into the root as well? The idea is that your scripts/tsd/intermediate files go into the root of the project and the build transpiles to js and the js goes into the wwwroot which is what you deploy.

Comment: this didnt help. Please have a look at https://www.dropbox.com/s/dgdibivnl4c55vf/Angular2Typescript.rar?dl=0.  By the way I am using beta 8. Please have a look at http://prntscr.com/9ax6gx

Comment: If you look in the angular2.d.ts file you'll see there's no actual typescript definitions there. You need to "npm install angular2", then the node module resolution will pick it up. Also, remove the spaces in your import statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97114/discussion-between-dotnetsparrow-and-daniel-cook).